# Service getting stopped even after using Alarm Manager

Tags: android

I need to run some functionality in my service all the time.

So I have used Alarm Manager to make my Service alive.

I am using invoking Service for each 30 mins.

But If I keep my android device idle for long time( I tested by kept the device idle for overnight) I observed that my Service is not executing my functions.

I can see the logs only upto nearly 2 hour's but after that my Service not running..

I just want know that how I can make my Service alive all the times..

Pl. help in this.

Answer (score 1):

Application Services cannot be persisted. http://www.androidguys.com/2009/09/09/diamonds-are-forever-services-are-not/

You have 3 options ([http://engineersaredumb.blogspot.com/2011/02/persistent-services-in-android.html][1] by https://stackoverflow.com/users/638122/andrew)

1. If you need services to wake up regularly, work and die, use the `AlarmManager`
2. If you need need your service to run continuously for a limited period of time, like a Music
   player, `setForeground()` on the service
3. If you need your service to keep running, but you can live with
   interruptions from time to time, return `START_STICKY` from
   `onStartCommand()`

All in all, Android will not let your Service run forever (unless it is a System service) .

Comment: He already tried point 1, he says he is using AlarmManager to start service every 30 mins

Comment: My intent was to list down all the options he has.